# How can I upadate a TextArea from another application that makes a thread to launch a GUI?

Tags: multithreading, javafx, fxml

I'm setting up a Server that launch a GUI with a Thread, in which i want to update a TextArea creating a sort of Log : when a Client connects or does something, but I can't get the GUI to update. In every way I tried I get a NullPointerException

Tried to get the Controller with some methods but with no luck

Server code

```
public class Server{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Thread l = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                javafx.application.Application.launch(Logger.class);
            }
        };
        l.start();
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8189);
            while(true){
               Socket s = null;
            try{
                s = server.accept();

                ObjectInputStream input = new 
                ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                ObjectOutputStream output = new 
                ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

                Thread t = new ClientHandler(s, input, output);
                t.start();
            }catch(IOException e){
                s.close();
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            }
        }

}
```

Controller code

```
public class Controller implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    public TextArea log = new TextArea();

    public void logger(String s){
        log.appendText(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
        log.setText("Log has started...");
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the NullPointerException is this line

```
@FXML
public TextArea log = new TextArea();
```

it is already being initialized in the FXML so just do

```
@FXML
public TextArea log;
```

Comment: Thanks, changed it but after that i can't append any text to the TextArea, tried to implement a method to get the controller but the result is the same : "NullPointerException"

Comment: Then the textarea is not initialized in your fxml can you post the code that calls your fxml and your fxml

Comment: Thanks for the response, i found the solution: on the controller file in the method initialize you return this and save the instance of the controller in a variable in the main file.